# Remove Selection Behaviour from Kendo Color Palette

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, color-palette

I am using the kendo color pallete control like so:

```
 $(".palette").kendoColorPalette({
      columns: 5,
      tileSize: {
         width: 34,
         height: 19
      },
      palette: [
         "#735096", "#a7447d", "#9d2b12", "#c7560a", "df7700",
         "#3f5caf", "#0293a0", "#4d9954", "#7e9c22", "#b18d00",
         "#00517f", "#000000", "#575757", "#818181", "#74661b"
      ],
      change: this.preview
});
```

Annoyingly when I select a color, the kendo grid applies the .k-state-selected class which sets a background colour thus overriding the tiles colour. Is there a way to disable this class being applied?

Comment: have you tried to set the property "select: preview"?

Comment: Yeah, that ended up working great, thanks!